# What rules were used wrong in Tabletop's episode for "Fortune and Glory"?

Tags: scoring

In the opening of the [Tabletop episode for *Fortune and Glory*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQMuu_7jn2I), a tabletop gaming series with Will Wheaton, there is a disclaimer in the opening saying that many rules were used wrongly. I liked the game, but I'm wondering: what was done wrong?

Comment: I tried to ask them on Twitter but they said they'll never tell: https://twitter.com/tabletop/status/440634747640098816

Answer (score 2):

From my experience of playing the game I think they may have got something wrong in the camping down/press on phase of Dangers. That or they made a mistake when you fail a danger to do with cliffhangers.

The full rulebook is published on [Flying Frog's website](http://www.flyingfrog.net/fortuneandglory/pdf%5CFANG_Rulebook_FINAL_WEB.pdf) if you want to check while watching the episode.